# Design database to allow for time based food menus

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, time

I'm trying to build a system that allows restaurants to create menus that can show based on time of day and day of week.

For example, there may be a standard menu, a happy hour menu, a specials menu, etc that all have their own items per menu and pricing per item. A cheese pizza could be $10 on Friday 10AM-2PM and $5.00 3PM - 5PM.

What's a good way to design the database so items can have various pricing (based on time of day and day of week) as well as be associated to various 'menus' (in order to categorize them)?

I currently have a system that doesn't really allow for this (since time-based menus weren't needed at the time).

*Would I need a menu_items_times table with a column for price, time start, time end?*

**venues table** - each individual restraunt (primary_menu_id) relates to a menu_id from menus table

```
    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | venue_id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | None    | auto_increment |
    | name             | varchar(256) | NO   |     | None    |                |
    | primary_menu_id  | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**menus table** each menu and what venue it belongs to

```
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | menu_id  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | None    | auto_increment |
    | venue_id | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | None    |  
    | name     | varchar(256) | NO   |     | None    |                |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**menu_items table** each individual menu item for a menu and what category (ie. 'drinks', 'food', 'specials' category) and 'category_index' for sorting the categories.

```
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | menu_item_id  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | none    | auto_increment |
    | menu_id       | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | none    |                |
    | name          | varchar(256) | NO   |     | none    |                |
    | price         | float        | NO   |     | none    |                |
    | category      | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | none    |                |
    | category_index| int(11)      | NO   |     | none    |                |
    +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**menu_items_categories view**

```
    +----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+
    | Field          | Type         | Collation |  Attributes | NULL | Extra   |
    +----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+
    | menu_id        | bigint(20)   |           |             | No   |         |
    | category       | varchar(64)  |           |             | No   |         |
    | category_index | int(11)      |           |             | No   |         |
    +----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by you need the `items to be associated to various 'menus'`??

Comment: I mean, a 'cheese pizza' could be part of a 'Happy Hour' menu from 4-6pm and have its own price, but it could also be a part of 'standard menu' with a different price for the other part of the day. So the same 'item' is on 2 'menus', but with different prices at different times.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 4 ways of doing this...

1. Add a `time_id` field to `menu_items`, that contains the id of a static array that contains times ... 1=>morning, 2=>evening, 3=>all-day, etc.
2. Same as #1, but make the field a VARCHAR that can be search in a LIKE (%%) query ... so `time_id` becomes something like ".8.9.10.11." for 8-11am, '.18.19.20.21." for 6-9pm ... a bit more messy, and LIKE queries are a little more intensive so probably not ideal.
3. Instead of a field in `menu_items`, add another table ... `menu_times` ... that contains `menu_item_id` and `time_id`s ... this may be faster than #2. It could even contain a `time_description` instead of `time_id`, such as "all morning" or "happy hour".
4. You could put `menu_times` between `menus` and `menu_items` ... so `menus` contained `menu_times`, which contained `menu_items`.

One thing to note about all of these solutions is that some of them require multiple `menu_items` for different prices ... which is not ideal. With solutions 1-3, however, you could solve this by moving the `price` into the `menu_times` table.

Comment: Thanks for the response neokio.

1) I'm not sure if that'll work since there would probably be a specific time (start/end time) and what day(s) it applies to.

2) Yeah, this may be a bit harder for me to implement and like you said may not be the most ideal.

3) This could maybe work. Although, wouldn't it be **menu_items_time ** instead since each item could have its own price based on that time? Would I also add 'price'? So there could be an entry per time for an item. 'Pizza' item could have a menu_items_time entry for 10AM-11AM, M/W/F, $6. And another entry 11AM - 10PM, M/W/F, $12.

Comment: Another thought would be to have menu_times and then menu_item_prices. Each menu could have a time, and menu_items_prices would be related to the times and menu_items.